# How to display different icon based on text value

Tags: javascript

I'm using jQuery.countdown to display multiple instances of several expiration dates on the same page and I have it set to display the number of days remaining (e.g. "45 days"). I've designed it so by default there is an associated background image of "icon-conditional-rule-pass.png".

I have the code that changes to icon-conditional-rule-fail.png if it shows 00 days, which works fine, but where I am struggling is that I want to create a period where a caution icon will display from lets say 1-60 days, I obviously will need to have "60 Days", "59 Days", etc., which is fine, I just can't figure out how (or if it's possible) to manipulate the code to work with multiple values. I'm assuming this can be done?

I've tried modifying/manipulating my code in all sorts of ways, but whenever I test, it only seems to work on the first text value and ignores the rest. Searching the web yields no results to what I'm trying to achieve.

```
$(".countdown").filter(function() {
    return $(this).text() === "00 Days";
  }).css("background-image", "url(/assets/icon-conditional-rule-fail.png)");
```

Want a single script that I can plug in multiple values into and have it return the desired caution image. I do want to create multiple scripts (e.g. 1 for displaying caution 30 days before expiration, 1 for 60, etc., but I'm assuming I'll just need to change the .countdown field to something else.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Personally, I'd break this up into four steps:

1. Create an array of `ranges`, which includes the number of `days` and the associated `icon`
2. For each `.countdown`, parse the amount of "Days" into a *number*
3. Using that number, find the corresponding range from step 1
4. Use the icon for that range

Not only does this leave you with one concise and reusable method, but it also allows you to update the ranges and/or icons easily by simply editing the `ranges` array.

```js
const ranges = [
  {
    days: 60, //60+ days
    icon: "icon-for-60plus-days.png"
  },
  {
    days: 30, //30-59 days
    icon: "icon-for-30plus-days.png"
  },
  {
    days: 1, //1-29 days
    icon: "icon-for-1plus-days.png"
  },
  {
    days: 0, //0 days
    icon: "icon-conditional-rule-fail.png"
  }
];

$(".countdown").css("background-image", function() {             //For each .countdown
  const daysAsInt = Number($(this).text().replace(" Days", "")); //Get the days as an integer
  const range = ranges.find(i => daysAsInt >= i.days);           //Find the range in the array
  return range && `url(/assets/${range.icon})`;                  //Set the background-image to the corresponding icon
});

//FOR DEMO PURPOSES ONLY
$(".countdown").each(function() { console.log($(this).text(),": ", $(this).css("background-image")); });
```

```css
span { display: block; }
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<span class="countdown">70 Days</span>
<span class="countdown">40 Days</span>
<span class="countdown">05 Days</span>
<span class="countdown">00 Days</span>
```

Comment: Doesn't seem to work, the fields that actually show the number of days remaining "e.g. 254 Days") actually have this code in them <div class="countdown" data-countdown="2019/12/31"></div> and then there is this script which is what is converting that to the actual "254 Days"

Comment: <script>
$('[data-countdown]').each(function() {
  var $this = $(this), finalDate = $(this).data('countdown');
  $this.countdown(finalDate, function(event) {
    $this.html(event.strftime('%D Days'));
  });
});
</script>

Comment: @Toddster As long as that script runs before the one provided in the answer, it should work.

Comment: That must have been the issue, script was in the wrong place. Appears to work perfectly, although doesn't seem to want to work for IE11 (I'm not going to lose sleep over it, since it's just an internal thing for me to use at work, and my Browser of choice if FireFox anyway.) Just an added bonus to have the icons. Thank you so much!

Comment: @Toddster Glad to have helped. Unfortunately IE11 does not support `.find()`, however there is an available [polyfill](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find#Polyfill) that adds IE11 support. If you found this answer helpful and adequate, please consider marking it accepted :)